# Missing values passing array variables from csv file to invoke-sqlcmd insert statement?

Tags: sql, powershell, foreach, import-csv, invoke-sqlcmd

I'm just learning PowerShell, I've built a script trying to import a `.CSV` file into my SQL Server database, and found that the following query was just appending the table.

```
$database = 'DATABASE'
$server = 'SERVER'
$table = 'TABLE'
Import-CSV \\TESTPATH\licenses_v2.csv  | 
ForEach-Object { 
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "insert into $table VALUES ('$($_.FirstName)','$($_.LastName)','$($_.Department)','$($_.Title)')" 
}
```

So in an effort to first `TRUNCATE` before `INSERT`, I've tested the following two scripts below:

```
$database = 'DATABASE'
$server = 'SERVER'
$table = 'TABLE'
Import-CSV \\TESTPATH\licenses_v2.csv | 
ForEach-Object { Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "truncate table $table; insert into $table VALUES ('$($_.FirstName)','$($_.LastName)','$($_.Department)','$($_.Title)')" 
}

$database = 'DATABASE'
$server = 'SERVER'
$table = 'TABLE'
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "truncate table $table"
Import-CSV \\TESTPATH\licenses_v2.csv | 
ForEach-Object { Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "insert into $table VALUES ('$($_.FirstName)','$($_.LastName)','$($_.Department)','$($_.Title)')" 
}
```

After testing those scripts, then using my original script at the top of the page, my table returns the same number of records from the `.CSV` insert, but they're all blank now, and this wasn't the case prior to testing those two separate `TRUNCATE` scripts (the file still has the same values in each record):

[image]

Querying the object from PowerShell it looks like the **select-object command returns all empty records** now:

```
import-csv \\TestPath\licenses_v2.csv | select-object FirstName,Department,Title
```

However, the **Import-CSV, does return the values** present in the file:

```
Import-CSV \\TestPath\licenses_v2.csv
```

Testing other SQL statements to insert literal SQL strings it appears that I'm still able to write to the table using `invoke-sqlcmd`, but (I may be wrong) I've somehow truncated the object values that powershell is reading from the file, even though the values are still in the file.

Do I need to restore PowerShell somehow or did i somehow alter my file system?

Also, I can query the very same file from SQL using the following script, so i'm clearly able to read the values but my PowerShell script for some reason isn't able to read the values using the import-csv command:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Department] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](150) NULL
) 
   BULK INSERT #TempTable
    FROM '\\TestPath\licenses_v2.csv'
    WITH
(
  FIRSTROW = 2,
  DATAFILETYPE='char', 
  FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
  TABLOCK,
  KEEPNULLS -- Treat empty fields as NULLs.
)
go
select * from #TempTable
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the missing delimiter.

I'm using a pipe delimited CSV, when the default is comma. Theres in my export script screen #1 because it creates a single object for every column. Which is why the headers empty, because powershell does not match any objects under those literal headers (since there's only a single header, named a combination of all.)

Note that Select can return headers when matched with literally nothing:

```
'' | Select Name,Date

Name Date
---- ----
```

---

To fix, just use `Import-Csv -Delimiter '|'`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters

> If you specify a character other than the actual string delimiter in the file, Import-Csv cannot create objects from the CSV strings. Instead, it returns the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your methods are prone to errors are SQL injection problems because you're concatenating strings for your queries. It would be much better to use parameterized queries (prepared statements), as it will avoid most if not all of that trouble. But it'll be more code for you to write.

Fortunately for you, the [`dbatools`](https://dbatools.io/) PowerShell module can simplify this and make it faster, safer, and more reliable with the [`Write-DbaDataTable`](https://dbatools.io/functions/write-dbadatatable/) function.

Install the module with `install-module dbatools` (assuming you're using PowerShell 5/WMF5; otherwise, you'll need to follow the alternate install instructions on the website).

```
import-module dbatools;
$database = 'DATABASE';
$server = 'SERVER';
$table = 'TABLE';
$MyData = import-csv \\TESTPATH\licenses_v2.csv | select-object FirstName,Department,Title;
Write-DbaDataTable -sqlinstance $server -database $database -table $table -inputobject $MyData;
```

If you need to truncate the table first, you can use the `-Truncate` switch.

Comment: Thank you, using this script I was able to write to the table but now the table is no longer reflecting **'BLANK' records** but **'NULL' literal values** as if its reading them as NULL in the file... But the file contains values. Why do you think that might be?

Comment: @lee Is it the string `NULL` or actual `NULL` values? Can you try the `-KeepNulls` switch?

Comment: It's a string value that says 'NULL' strings... The values written to the table are not actually null missing values, its a value and that value is a string that reads "NULL"... I'm wondering if trying to place the truncate statement in different parts of those two test scripts may have somehow overriden the command or way the objects are being written to the table because i can query the CSV values from the command line and they're returned... But when i try to write them to a SQL Table they return as "NULL" strings, not to be confused with NULL missing values.

Comment: What would the syntax of that switch -keepnulls script look like?

Comment: @Lee it would be exactly that - add `-KeepNulls` to the list of parameters passed to `write-dbadatatable`

Comment: I've revised my question and added it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782136/powershell-csv-values-piped-to-select-objects-returns-empty-records because it seems the issue is happening not just as a result of trying to write to SQL, but somehow at the file level for powershell. (I assume)

Comment: Now that i've added the -KeepNulls, the values in the file are written to my table as actual NULL missing values, and no longer "NULL" literal strings.